# What is the way to show small part of an article and make it open with read more link in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am a newbie coder. I have learned a lot in the few weeks. Now I am making my blog site.
What I want is , show the limited part of  6 or 8 articles in the content div and make a read more link to show the article.

Can you tell me a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the string helper and use the word_limiter, character_limiter (google for docs)

Or, contain a paragraph called "Summary" (varchar(255)) different to your main "Content" field (TEXT).

Answer (score 0):

Initially load string helper and do as follows

```
word_limiter("data",limit);
```

[You can check it here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html)